# I can't install cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods

sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:715:in `verify_gem_home'     /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:905:in` pre_install_checks'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:303:in `install'     /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:105:in` install'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:195:in `block in install'  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in` each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in `install'   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:215:in` install_gem'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:231:in `block in install_gems'    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:224:in` each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:224:in `install_gems'     /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:170:in` execute'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command.rb:328:in `invoke_with_build_args'    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:253:in` invoke_command'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:193:in `process_args'  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:151:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:52:in `run'     /usr/bin/gem:21:in` <main>'

....................